# Pass file (model weight) as an argument to Docker Image

Tags: python, docker, machine-learning, dockerfile

I have a problem with loading a file to a Docker image. I would like to pass the file path as an argument and then be able to access (read) it from inside the image.

#### File *model.py*

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--image-path', type=str)
  parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str)
  args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

  sample_image = args.image_path
  print("Sample:", sample_image)
  print("Model:", args.model_dir)
  print("Done.")
```

#### File *Dockerfile*

```yaml
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt update && apt install -y python3-pip

COPY model.py model.pth.tar ./

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "./model.py", "--model_dir"]
CMD ["./model.pth.tar"]
```

From my understanding, the combination of these ENTRYPOINT and CMD should have worked. But I don't have any luck.

I managed to pass the required image (picture) by mounting:

`docker build -t my_model --progress=plain .`

`docker run -v /tmp:/tmp/myfilesdocker my_model --image-path=happy.jpg`

However, I don't want to do that with my `model.pth.tar` (model weight). I want it to be passed by default (or any other way that works and doesn't require mounting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might change your Python code to also accept values from environment variables.  Probably the easiest way to do this is to set `default` values for the arguments using `os.getenv`; the `argparse` module doesn't do this on its own.

```py
parser.add_argument('--image-path', type=str, default=os.getenv('IMAGE_PATH'))
parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default=os.getenv('MODEL_DIR'))
```

Once you've done that, you can set the default value as an environment variable in the Dockerfile, and not worry about the `ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD` split.

```bash
ENV MODEL_DIR=./model.pth.tar
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "./model.py"]
```

```bash
docker run -v /tmp:/data my_model --image-path=/data/happy.jpg
docker run -v /tmp:/data -e IMAGE_PATH=/data/happy.jpg my_model
```

In your original code it seems like the `--image-path` is read as a normal file; I've used an absolute path here to make it clear where it comes from.

Comment: (If the environment-variable setup works for you, I have a general preference for `CMD` over `ENTRYPOINT` for the main container command: it simplifies a couple of cases of debugging, and it's more compatible with the entrypoint-wrapper pattern.  If you also make your script executable and start it with a shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` then you can replace the `ENTRYPOINT` with `CMD ["./model.py"]`, which isn't too much to re-type in a `docker run` line if needed.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been stuck on the issue for more than 5 hours. I made all the changes that you suggested. Everything was great apart the additionof shebang line and replacement of `ENTRYPOINT` with `CMD`. If I do that I get `docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./model.py": permission denied: unknown.` I believe it can be connected with the fact that I am using github's codespaces and I just may not have a permission to do this?

Comment: Hate to bother but if you would like to help me with one more issue I will really appricaite it. My real-life use case is to feed an image to container so that my ML model will run and do some classifcation on the image. However, every time when I run `docker run` a new container is created. I am worried about space overhead that may cause. Is this a normal behavior, or is there any way to avoid creating container every time (e.g., reusing the same container by feeding images to it and getting output).

Comment: Creating a new container every time is normal, and shouldn't be particularly expensive (it is not substantially more overhead than a new Linux process being created when you run `./model.py` locally; the ML task will be much more expensive than the per-container overhead).  Consider `docker run --rm` so the container deletes itself when it's done.

Comment: You might need to `chmod +x model.py` to get it to run without explicitly naming the interpreter.  You can commit that permission change to source control.

Answer (score 1):

In general, containers don't have access to the host file system without being given explicit access through mounts. This is for security reasons.

The only way I can think of giving a container access to a file without mounting the file, is to pipe it into the container and then read it from stdin inside the container. You need to use the `-i` option on `docker run` when you do that.

As an example, you can take the contents of `/etc/os-release` on the host and pass it to `cat` inside the container like this

```
cat /etc/os-release | docker run --rm -i debian cat
```

The container will then print out the contents of the host's `/etc/os-relase`.

Of course, this way only lets you read the content of the file. You can't update it. But if I'm reading your question correctly, you don't need to update the model data.

Answer (score 1):

Your Dockerfile has a typo in the `--model_dir` part. Try the following
`ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "./model.py", "--model-dir"]`

Comment: Thank you. I changed it now the output is: `usage: model.py [-h] [--image-path IMAGE_PATH] [--model-dir MODEL_DIR]
model.py: error: argument --model-dir: expected one argument`

Comment: Try merging ENTRYPOINT and CMD in your Dockerfile as such: `ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "model.py", "--model-dir", "./model.pth.tar"]`